Compare two cells and input timestamp in third if they do not match Google Apps Script
I have two lists that include IDs that I'd like to include a timestamp to a cell if the two columns don't match. I am able to do this easily with a function, but I need something that will act as a trigger for another action and a formula solution won't do that.
I have very little experience in Google Apps Scripts and I don't even know where to begin. I've tried searching here and all over the internet and haven't found anything yet.
Below is an example of the result I would like to see:

Thanks in advance for your help!

Compare Values and Add Timestamp If Not the Same
You may use simple if-else (in this case ternary) to compare if the two values are the same and then return timestamp when the two values are not the same.
Script
You may use the following script:
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data1 = ss.getRange(2, 5, ss.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  var data2 = ss.getRange(2, 7, ss.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();
  var out = data1.map((x, i) => (x == "" && data2[i] == "") ? [""] : parseInt(x) == parseInt(data2[i]) ? [""] : [Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")]);
  ss.getRange(2,6,out.length,1).setValues(out);
}

Sample Data & Output

References:

formatDate
Conditional (ternary) Operator


Feel free to comment if you have any questions about the answer posted above.

That almost works. But it puts the timestamp in any cell where one of the compare cells is blank

I see. Let me work on it. But basically, we will just add another condition wherein no output will be made if both columns are blank. However, based on your sample, if one column has value and the other is blank, there will also be a timestamp? Or should there be no comparison when there is a blank?

clarification, it puts the timestamp in where both the compare cells are blank in addition to where they are different.

Like in my sample, it puts the timestamp in F5, F6, & F7, as well as where I want it.

I have added the condition checking if both columns have no answers then no timestamp will be placed. Kindly check on your side.

That's it! Thank you so much for your help!
